# Angularjs select in templateCache

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

well I get some data from php from a data base, and then have it in angularjs like that:

```
stuff= 
[
    {name:'stuff1', id:'1'},
    {name:'stuff2', id:'2'},
    {name:'stuff3', id:'3'},
    {name:'stuff4', id:'4'}
];
```

and i want to add this in a select that  it is in a  templateCache

```
-code-
.run(['$templateCache',function($templateCache,$scope){
$templateCache.put('/dialogs/editUser.html',
-code-
+'<select data-ng-options="s.name for s in stuff" data-ng-model="selected_s"> </select>'
-code-
}])
```

I'm using the angular-dialog-service code from m-e-conroy, and build a custom dialog.

It supposed to be a dialog that is showing up, if you want to edit something, then you should select from 'stuff', but i couldn't figure out how. Maybe someone could gave me a tip, or is that even possible?? The other Code is working, and i dont get an error, just an empty select

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to that you are using whole object as model and select in angular don't really work with it. Change your code to work with id instead.

```
<select data-ng-options="s.id as s.name for s in stuff" data-ng-model="selected_s"> </select>
```

Comment: <option value="?" selected="selected"></option> 
    
I tried your solution, but it still dont add the options to the select

Comment: Should be related to templateCache itself, because I tried simple angularjs select and it worked. And here I can't help, sorry.

Comment: Okey, then i sould try to find out how that works with the templateCache...., thanks anyway! (: